# Pytest: load and run test from notebook

Tags: pytest, databricks

In the [official Databricks example](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/test-notebooks.html#separate-test-code-from-the-notebook) a notebook is created which runs tests with [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

- The notebook imports another notebook (containing the `test_*` methods) with `%run`
- The test is launched in the notebook with `unittest.main(...`

I would like to do the same thing with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/):

- I imported the notebook containing th `test_*` methods using  `%run`
- I tried to launch the tests with `retcode = pytest.main([])` but I always get `no tests ran`

Notebook containing the tests (notebook_my_test)

```
def test_trivial2():
    myvar=True
    assert myvar == True
```

Main notebook:

```
%run ./notebook_my_test

import pytest
retcode = pytest.main([])
```